# PayPal - Instant Payment Notification / doDirectPayment in PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have built a IPN Listener and tested it with the IPN Simulator in sandbox and it works fine, however when I add the "NOTIFYURL" parameter and set it to my IPN Listener I do not get any notifications from my listener, but payment still goes through.

**Is there something else I have to do to get this to work?**

Here's my codes

My IPN Listener (for the purposes of testing it simply Imports the entire result into a SQL Table)

```
 include "dbconnect.php";
$request = "cmd=_notify-validate";
foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue){
    $email .= "$varname: $varvalue\n";  

    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') and get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  
        $varvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($varvalue));
    }
    else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $request .= "&$varname=$varvalue";
}

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`nvps`) VALUES ('".$email."')");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.paypal.com");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The portion of my payment processing script that interacts with paypal:

```
// Store request params in an array
$request_params = array
                    (
                    'METHOD' => 'DoDirectPayment', 
                    'USER' => $api_username, 
                    'PWD' => $api_password, 
                    'SIGNATURE' => $api_signature, 
                    'VERSION' => $api_version, 
                    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',                  
                    'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                    'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'Visa', 
                    'ACCT' => '4887864152287206',                       
                    'EXPDATE' => '072018',          
                    'CVV2' => '123', 
                    'FIRSTNAME' => 'Tester', 
                    'LASTNAME' => 'Testerson', 
                    'STREET' => '707 W. Bay Drive', 
                    'CITY' => 'Largo', 
                    'STATE' => 'FL',                    
                    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US', 
                    'ZIP' => '33770', 
                    'AMT' => '100.00', 
                    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD', 
                    'NOTIFYURL' => 'http://www.mysite.com/ipnlistener.php',
                    'DESC' => 'Testing Payments Pro' 
                    );

// Loop through $request_params array to generate the NVP string.
$nvp_string = '';
foreach($request_params as $var=>$val)
{
    $nvp_string .= '&'.$var.'='.urlencode($val);    
}

// Send NVP string to PayPal and store response
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
echo $result.'<br /><br />';
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`nvps`) VALUES ('".$result."')");
```

**Why aren't I getting my notifications?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you take a look at the PHP IPN script over at https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/IPN_PHP.txt?

Leave `USE_SANDBOX` and `USE_DEBUG` enabled and create an empty file called 'ipn.txt' in the same directory (writable by the webserver).

This will log all steps of the IPN process (receiving it, posting it back, verifying the results, etc).  Should anything, that should make it clear.

Comment: Thank you, i like this better much better than using my database, but the problem persists. It works fine with the ipn simulator but still nothing from my script

Comment: It's a means of debugging; what's the contents of your 'ipn.log' file?

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of the ipn listener is for paypal to pass back payment info so you can process it, it will not send you any notifications as such unless you add things like a log file, where each payment status is logged or send email to yourself about processed payments (whether they failed or not)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but you lost me at "log file" .. how do i do that? can you provide a refernec/ link?

Comment: i  can understand not sending any initial post on payment, but i went into the sandbox and did a refund and still nothing..

Comment: thanks ok, i understand that but i thought he was referring to a paypal logging function, liam clearly did not read my question very well because i am inserting the response into my database. -1 for confusing me and wasting my time.

Comment: seems you are confusing yourself, like you expect paypal to miraculously generate an awesome popup notification or something. you need to code your own notifications, in your code i dont see any payment validation in order to do this

Comment: Dude, look at my code `mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (nvps) VALUES ('".$email."')");` If the script were recieving any posts of any kind they would be logged in my database. Further, i mentioned that it was working in the simulator, so clearly, the listener is not the issue.

Comment: haha ok, is the sandbox url still being used when you use it outside of sandbox?

Comment: i have not taken it out of the sandbox yet.